# Recharts - How to improve the visualization for closest numbers

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recharts

I have a chart where the values are too close like:

- Value A -> 3.7747199435
- Value B -> 3.775531821
- Value C -> 3.7754975674
- Value D -> 3.8358619466
- Value E -> 3.8856710034

and I'm getting a visualization with a soft difference between the points.

[image: smooth chart values]

Here is the chart code:

```js
<ResponsiveContainer>
  <AreaChart
    data={data}
    margin={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
    baseValue={['dataMin', 'auto']}
  >

    <Area
      dataKey="value"
      stroke="#6dffd3"
      strokeWidth={1}
    />
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```

So, how can i improve the visualization of the chart having a better contrast of the values?

Comment: You could multiply the numbers by e.g. 10000 for the visualization and see if that helps

Comment: @Tholle I got the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the YAxis component with the hide attribute.

```
<ResponsiveContainer>
  <AreaChart
    data={data}
    margin={{ top: 0, left: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0 }}
  >
    <YAxis domain={['auto', 'auto']} hide />
    <Area dataKey="value" stroke="#6dffd3" strokeWidth={1} />
  </AreaChart>
</ResponsiveContainer>
```